# Json Schema example for oneOf objects

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I am trying to figure out how oneOf works by building a schema which validates two different object types. For example a person (firstname, lastname, sport) and vehicles (type, cost).

Here are some sample objects:

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "sport": "football"}

{"vehicle":"car", "price":20000}
```

The question is what have I done wrongly and how can I fix it. Here is the schema:

```
{
    "description": "schema validating people and vehicles", 
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "oneOf" ],
    "properties": { "oneOf": [
        {
            "firstName": {"type": "string"}, 
            "lastName": {"type": "string"}, 
            "sport": {"type": "string"}
        }, 
        {
            "vehicle": {"type": "string"}, 
            "price":{"type": "integer"} 
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

When I try to validate it in this parser:

```
https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/
```

I get the following error:

```
   [ {
  "level" : "fatal",
  "message" : "invalid JSON Schema, cannot continue\nSyntax errors:\n[ {\n  \"level\" : \"error\",\n  \"schema\" : {\n    \"loadingURI\" : \"#\",\n    \"pointer\" : \"/properties/oneOf\"\n  },\n  \"domain\" : \"syntax\",\n  \"message\" : \"JSON value is of type array, not a JSON Schema (expected an object)\",\n  \"found\" : \"array\"\n} ]",
  "info" : "other messages follow (if any)"
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/oneOf"
  },
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "message" : "JSON value is of type array, not a JSON Schema (expected an object)",
  "found" : "array"
} ]
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try this:

```json
{
  "description": "schema validating people and vehicles",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "sport": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "vehicle": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does `oneOf` help in validating the request? I can't see any jackson annotation for `oneOf` during pojo conversion

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni, that is a jackson specific problem. It is not easy to translate oneOf semantics to some programming languages such as java. You need some construct like Disjoint sets, Discriminated Unions, Union Types... that other languages have.

Comment: @jruizaranguren there any library other than jackson that handles this case ? or else we would have to add custom validators in our codebase.

Comment: Is it required to have `"type" : "object"` on the root? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @AlirezaMirian, if you do not explicitly specify it, any other type would satisfy the specification, because "oneOf" only applies to types.  It is ignored for other types.

Comment: @jruizaranguren >""oneOf" only applies to types. It is ignored for other types" - It's wrong. But in this particular case, "type: object" is needed, because the specs inside `oneOf` do not have any type information and the type should be specified *somewhere*.

Comment: @Ark-kun, it is convenient, not required. If type is omitted, unwanted objects may be validated.  For instance, an empty object validates my schema, which is not probably what you want. But the question was about oneOf usage and syntax.

Comment: @jruizaranguren >"an empty object validates my schema, which is not probably what you want" - Well, your second schema has no required properties, so an empty object is valid against it. What if you added required properties? AFAIK, with oneOf, you create multiple object schema variants by adding the contents of a oneOf section to the surrounding schema node. All resulting schema variant must be valid schemas and for the object to be considered validated against the schema, it needs to be valid against exactly one variant.

Comment: @Ark-kun, we can think of many what-if situations, and your explanations of json-schema are valid. But the question is about oneOf syntax, not about modeling a concrete problem. I find this discussion off-topic.

Comment: I guess I just do not understand what exactly you meant by ""oneOf" only applies to types. It is ignored for other types.". And I consider "it is convenient, not required." to be wrong. The `type` must be set either outside `oneOf` or inside all `oneOf` variants. Not omitted. Not specified both ways.

Comment: ok, I understand the issue. By saying "it is convenient, not required" I mean the standard does not  enforce its usage. As most of things in json-schema, it must be read as: "if your data is an object, then apply the oneOf constraint", "if your data is not an object, ignore this clause".

Comment: And the standard also says that each element in oneOf must be a valid json-schema. Thus, specifying the type is correct. It may help defining the constraints.

Comment: Can you have a oneOf _and_ properties on the top type?

Comment: @justin.m.chase, Should be that a new question to S.O.?

Comment: This 100% does not work, json schema is hopelessly broken, its not your fault.

Answer (score 28):

**oneOf** need to be used inside a **schema** to work.

Inside **properties**, it's like another property called "oneOf" without the effect you want.

Comment: I'm not saying your wrong, but can you provide a source for this information please? =]

Comment: Well it makes sense from deduction of what `properties` does, i.e. why would `properties` ever make a special case for keys named `oneOf`? Pretty much common sense it works this way now that I think of it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is what I found also.  oneOf inside of properties does not work.