# invalid JSON Schema exception in RestAssured, while validating against schema from swagger

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I am writing TestNG tests with RestAssured to test a REST service. I copied the response schema from Swagger page and validating response with this schema. When I manually validated the response with schema, it is fine. When I validate the same from my script, it logs an exception.

My code:

```
given().headers("X-Correlation-Id",correlationId)
 .get(url).then().assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("OffersByDivStoreSchema.json"));
```

JSON Schema:

```
[
  {
    "couponAmount": 0,
    "couponAmt": 0,
    "couponDescription": "string",
    "couponNumber": "string",
    "creationDate": "string",
    "displayStartDate": "string",
    "divNumber": "string",
    "divStoreCoupon": "string",
    "expirationDate": "string",
    "maxSavings": 0,
    "minPurchaseAmount": 0,
    "minPurchaseQty": 0,
    "offerType": "string",
    "promoDescription": "string",
    "promoType": "string",
    "rewardYN": true,
    "updateDate": "string"
  }
]
```

Actual Response:

```
[
{
"divNumber": "999-00001",
"couponNumber": "5",
"divStoreCoupon": "999-00001-5",
"displayStartDate": "2017-11-17",
"expirationDate": "2017-10-21",
"updateDate": "2017-12-02",
"creationDate": "2018-01-12",
"couponAmount": 0.36735077591857157,
"minPurchaseAmount": -2026457608,
"minPurchaseQty": -767686725,
"maxSavings": 0.14174878169207628,
"couponDescription": "This is a Test",
"offerType": "MD",
"rewardYN": true,
"promoDescription": "This is a Test",
"promoType": "This is a Test",
"couponAmt": 0.9053900149839325
},
{
"divNumber": "999-00001",
"couponNumber": "2",
"divStoreCoupon": "999-00001-2",
"displayStartDate": "2018-01-09",
"expirationDate": "2017-08-13",
"updateDate": "2017-08-11",
"creationDate": "2017-12-05",
"couponAmount": 0.21459988049947543,
"minPurchaseAmount": -905064853,
"minPurchaseQty": 1016266945,
"maxSavings": 0.6997004570836415,
"couponDescription": "This is a Test",
"offerType": "MD",
"rewardYN": true,
"promoDescription": "This is a Test",
"promoType": "This is a Test",
"couponAmt": 0.36784946303275545
}
]
```

My imports include:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.expect;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath;
```

Here is my exception:

```
io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.InvalidSchemaException: fatal: invalid JSON Schema, cannot continue
Syntax errors:
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "file:/C:/SOA_Scripts/spel-tests-offers/build/resources/test/OffersByDivStoreSchema.json#",
    "pointer" : ""
  },
  "domain" : "syntax",
  "message" : "JSON value is of type array, not a JSON Schema (expected an object)",
  "found" : "array"
} ]
    level: "fatal"


    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesSafely(JsonSchemaValidator.java:233)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesSafely(JsonSchemaValidator.java:75)
    at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:65)
    at org.hamcrest.Matcher$matches.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcher.validate(BodyMatcher.groovy:76)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcher$validate$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup$_validate_closure2.doCall(BodyMatcherGroup.groovy:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3140)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup.validate(BodyMatcherGroup.groovy:47)
    at io.restassured.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup$validate$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:458)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:643)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.content(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:94)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$content$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:244)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:262)
    at com.kroger.spel.services.OffersByDivStore.validateOffersForStore(OffersByDivStore.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
Caused by: com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.InvalidSchemaException: fatal: invalid JSON Schema, cannot continue
```

Can someone please suggest what is going wrong here.

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Just noticed that missed it in my post. Added the exception now :(

Comment: The error was already adressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014650/json-schema-example-for-oneof-objects), sadly, the answer provides no explanation, but maybe you can identify the lingering problem?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan I found the cause. I used the model schema from swagger-ui to validate against, instead of actual schema from swagger's v2/api-docs.json. When I changed the schema, the same code worked.

Comment: Glad it works now, if you found the precise cause, you could post your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I copied the schema from Model Schema on the swagger-ui.html page. But, noticed that this is a representation of response. Actual schema is created on /v2/api-docs.json page. Had to work on a little as there were so many definitions reused and had to bring them all together into one schema file each end point. Below is my final schema document.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "couponAmount": {
        "type": "number",
        "format": "double"
      },
      "couponAmt": {
        "type": "number",
        "format": "double"
      },
      "couponDescription": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "couponNumber": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "creationDate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "displayStartDate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "divNumber": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "divStoreCoupon": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "expirationDate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "maxSavings": {
        "type": "number",
        "format": "double"
      },
      "minPurchaseAmount": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      },
      "minPurchaseQty": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      },
      "offerType": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "promoDescription": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "promoType": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "rewardYN": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "updateDate": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same code worked, after updating the schema. Thanks [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372723/nathan), your reference helped me resolving this.