# For json-schema how can I declare a type for the json

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How can I declare multiple schemas and let a validator select one depending on a property?

For example I would like this json to be validated against second schema for type2

```
{
    "id2": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"],

    "schemaToValidate" : "type2"
}
```

A first schema definition for object of type1:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["id1"],
    "schemaForType" : "type1"
}
```

A second schema definition for object of type2:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["id2"],
    "schemaForType" : "type2"
}
```

I tried to find a sample for this at http://json-schema.org/example1.html but didn't realized if is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have multiple schema depending on a type but there is an alternative: change your example to use oneOf (also simplified to be easier on the schema):

```
{
    "Type2" : {
      "id2": 1
    }
}
```

And with a schema that work on one of Type1 and Type2 can be added:

```
{
    "description" : "schema validating Type1 and Type2",
    "type" : "object",
    "oneOf" : [{
        "properties" : {
            "Type1" : {
                "type": "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "id1" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        },
        "required" : [ "Type1" ]
    }, {
        "properties" :  {
            "Type2" :  {
               "type": "object",
               "properties" :  {
                   "id2" :  {
                      "type" : "integer"
                   }
              },
              "additionalProperties" : false
            }
        },
       "required" : ["Type2"]
    }
]
}
```

[Another example of AnyOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014650/json-schema-example-for-oneof-objects)